# New calendar in Kerio via CalDav: Which URI is corrent?

Tags: http, caldav

I implemented a CalDav client and now I tried to connect it to Kerio. 
However I cannot add a new calendar.

The discovery seems to be all right:
current-user-principal
calendar-home-set
Both found and URIs are returned.

Now I usually generate a UUID for a new calendar resource and attach that to the calendar URI to create a calendar. It looks something like this:

```
https://mail.XXXXX.de/caldav/full-calendars/XXXXX.de/firstname.lastname/6B514D253FC148318E15F97486C6658B/
```

Apparently I am not allowed to post links, that is the reason that link looks a bit strange.

My MKCALENDAR body is:

```
<C:mkcalendar xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
<D:set>
<D:prop>
<D:displayname>calendar name</D:displayname>
</D:prop>
</D:set>
</C:mkcalendar>
```

I also tried MKCOL, same result:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Error 501 Not Implemented</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY><H1>501 Not Implemented</H1>The requested feature is not supported by this server. (URI /caldav/full-calendars/XXXXX.de/firstname.lastname/CA27A9C9CDD24BCFB2B13F1BBFAC96EB/)
<BR>
<BR>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Do I have to turn it on in Kerio? Why does the discovery work then?

Thank you a lot!

Til

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing Kerio but knowing CalDAV quite well, I would say it's likely that you are not using the correct url. The url *should* be the *new* url of the calendar you want to create, at a location where calendars are allowed to be created.

So as a rule of thumb, you could find the collection where other calendars are (or better yet, use a location from the `calendar-home-set` property) and add a new path component to the end of the url.

For example, if your calendar collection has a path like:

```
/user/calendars/
```

The target of `MKCALENDAR` (or `MKCOL`) should be:

```
/users/calendars/[some-random-string]
```

`some-random-string` can be anything, it's not restricted to a UUID.

If you are still having problems, these are the potential alternative reasons.

1. There's a bug in Kerio, or a misconfiguration that prevents these HTTP methods.
2. Kerio explicitly simply doesn't allow creating new calendars via MKCALENDAR.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. The URL result of the calendar-home-set request is: /full-calendars/XXXXX.de/firstname.lastname/ and the base URL is https://mail.XXXXX.de/caldav/

Comment: Then that would suggest that something is wrong with the server, or you are simply forbidden from doing the request I think

Answer (score 0):

So the answer ist simple, actually:
    https://mail.XXXXX.de/full-calendars/XXXXX.de/firstname.lastname/6B514D253FC148318E15F97486C6658B/

That is the url. Without the /caldav/ part. 
Cheers.

Comment: Why was that answer downvoted? For the dicovery you need the url:
    https://mail.XXXXX.de/caldav. 
The calendar home set url is: 
    /full-calendars/XXXXX.de/firstname.lastname/

I was mistaken just to attach the calendar set to the start url. You need to strip the start url of the /caldav/ part und attach the calendar home set. Then add a random string and make a calendar in that location.